# parsing through csv document for address lookup

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I have been coding a simple C# application that carries out an address search by parsing a csv file. The user simply types in a part of the address and the full address is returned after the csv file is parsed.

This is the GUI so far:

[image]

where the element names are as follows:

- Combobox Field = AddressEntry
- Search Button = SearchButton
- Clear Button = ClearButton
- Exit Button = ExitButton

The csv file I am parsing from has rows of varying column lengths, and my aim is to loop through the each row/column to return the first closest match after the user clicks the search button. This is a sample of the contents of the CSV file:

```
MK1 1AS, Royal Mail, Bletchley Delivery Office, Dane Road, Bletchley, Milton Keynes
MK1 1AX, Webbs Tool Hire, Unit 1-3, Stadium Business Court, Denbigh West Industrial Estate, Denbigh Road, Bletchley, Milton Keynes
MK1 1AX, Crown Precision Engineering Ltd, Unit 4-5, Stadium Business Court, Denbigh West Industrial Estate, Denbigh Road, Bletchley, Milton Keynes
MK1 1AX, Unit 6, Stadium Business Court, Denbigh West Industrial Estate, Denbigh Road, Bletchley, Milton Keynes
MK4 4FL, 2, Levens Hall Drive, Westcroft, Milton Keynes
MK4 4FL, 28, Levens Hall Drive, Westcroft, Milton Keynes
MK46 5EF, 1, Mow Mead, Olney
MK46 5EF, 16, Mow Mead, Olney
MK2 2RD, 55, Westfield Road, Bletchley, Milton Keynes
MK2 2RD, 81, Westfield Road, Bletchley, Milton Keynes
MK12 5EG, 1, Woodland View, Wolverton, Milton Keynes
MK12 5EG, 20, Woodland View, Wolverton, Milton Keynes
MK13 7BX, 1, Harrowden, Bradville, Milton Keynes
MK16 8EU, 70, Queens Avenue, Newport Pagnell
MK7 7DT, 1, Spearmint Close, Walnut Tree, Milton Keynes
MK18 1JL, H S B C, Market Hill, Buckingham
```

I have tried coding this, but at the moment I get a blank message box whenever I try search for something. Furthermore, at the moment it appears that I am only searching through one column as opposed to all of them (column 1) and returning the results from that column only. How do I expand my search to include all columns?

```
    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String addressText = GetAddress(AddressEntry.Text);
        MessageBox.Show(addressText);
    }

    String GetAddress(String addressText)
    {
        var strLines = File.ReadLines("pca_mk_addresslist.csv");
        foreach (var line in strLines)
        {
            if (line.Split(',')[1].Equals(addressText))
                return line.Split(',')[1];
        }

        return "";
    }
```

Comment: CSV parsing is a thing you should not write yourself - see: http://blog.newrelic.com/2014/07/08/7-things-never-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing loop loops over all lines of input, and in its body you split each line into an array, but only access a single element of the array for comparison.

You need to compare *each* element of your array with your input, e.g.

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("pca_mk_addresslist.csv")
{
    var fields = line.Split(',');

    foreach(var field in fields)
    {
        if(field == addressText)
            return fields[1]
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Also, this, and your existing code, will only return the first match even if there are two exact matches in your file. Both have no guards against a line with only one column of data.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var line in strLines)
{
   var result = line.Split(',').FirstOrDefault(x => x == addressText);

   if (result != null)
         return result;
}
```

Comment: where does this code sit? I've done the following http://pastebin.com/DZ2CLeFN but get the following error message `Error 1 'AddressLookup.Form1.GetAddress(string)': not all code paths return a value` at line 10 in the pastebin example.